# Show message in specified time

Tags: c#, api, telegram-bot

I am making a telegram C# bot and I want my bot lock group and I use timespan for this and its work but I want exactly five minutes before lock group shows a message for users but my bot didn't send any messages automatically.
I am so beginner and didn't find any thing online for help.

Thank you for your help.

```
TimeSpan Start = new TimeSpan(20,0,0);
TimeSpan End = new TimeSpan(21,0,0);
TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

TimeSpan risingStart1 = new TimeSpan(19, 55, 0);
            

if (now == risingStart1)
{            
    Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id , "Group will lock for 5 min.");
}
else if (Start < now && now < End)
{
    Bot.DeleteMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, e.Message.MessageId);
}
```

PS: Timespan work for locking group.

Comment: Is your bot always running (like a windows service)? And on that bot, you need to execute some action at a given time, is that it?

Comment: Please provide a minimal-reproducible-example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes my bot always running. And In a given time should do some works like send a message or delete messages.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps:

```
public class Repeater
{
    private readonly List<DateTime> _checkpoints;
    private readonly Action _action;
    private readonly Func<Task> _asyncAction;
    private readonly Timer _timer;

    private Thread _processingThread;

    public Repeater(List<DateTime> checkpoints, Action action)
    {
        _checkpoints = checkpoints;

        _timer = new Timer
        {
            AutoReset = false,
            Enabled = false
        };
        _timer.Elapsed += TimerCheckpoint_Elapsed;
        _timer.Elapsed += CalculateNextExecution;

        _action = action;
        _asyncAction = null;
    }

    public Repeater(List<DateTime> checkpoints, Func<Task> action)
    {
        _checkpoints = checkpoints;

        _timer = new Timer
        {
            AutoReset = false,
            Enabled = false
        };
        _timer.Elapsed += TimerCheckpoint_Elapsed;
        _timer.Elapsed += CalculateNextExecution;

        _asyncAction = action;
        _action = null;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        ReinitializeTimer();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        //_thrProcessaCheckpoints?.Abort();
        _timer?.Stop();
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
    
    private void TimerCheckpoint_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_processingThread != null && _processingThread.IsAlive) return;

        _processingThread = new Thread(async () => await ThreadStart())
        {
            IsBackground = true,
            Name = "Timer Processing Thread"
        };

        try { _processingThread.Start(); } catch { /* ignored */ }
    }

    private async Task ThreadStart()
    {
        if (_asyncAction == null)
            _action();
        else
            await _asyncAction();
    }

    private void CalculateNextExecution(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReinitializeTimer();
    }

    private void ReinitializeTimer()
    {
        _timer.Interval = CalculateNextInterval(_checkpoints);
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private static double CalculateNextInterval(List<DateTime> checkpoints)
    {
        double min = double.MaxValue;
        var dateTime = DateTime.Now;

        // Calculate how much time is left to the next checkpoint
        foreach (var date in checkpoints)
        {
            TimeSpan timeForNextCheckpoint;

            // If it's in the same time, calculate how much time is left
            if (date.TimeOfDay > dateTime.TimeOfDay)
                timeForNextCheckpoint = date.TimeOfDay - dateTime.TimeOfDay;
            // If not, calculate how much time is left, counting a day
            else
                timeForNextCheckpoint = TimeSpan.FromHours(24) - (dateTime.TimeOfDay - date.TimeOfDay);

            if (Math.Abs(timeForNextCheckpoint.TotalMilliseconds) < min)
            {
                min = Math.Abs(timeForNextCheckpoint.TotalMilliseconds);
            }
        }

        return min;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var myRepeater = new Repeater(new List<DateTime>{ new DateTime(2020,19,11, 19, 55, 00) }, () => MyMethodCall());
myRepeater.Start(); // call on your application start
myRepeater.Stop(); // call on your application stop
```

You just need to provide a list of datetimes containing the hours that your task needs to be executed, and a method that will be executed at such time. The constructor also have an overload that receives an async method should you need it.

```
var myAsyncRepeater = new Repeater(_cfg.ConfiguracaoBaixaAdiamentos.Checkpoints,
            async () => await MyMethodCallAsync());
```